# var x; ... x.trim(); Why sometimes it allows but sometimes it makes the rest of the code stop working?

Tags: javascript

This minor issue causes me 5 hours to fix. Finally I figured out. See this code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   var x;
   .... // a lot of codes here
   var k=x.trim();

</script>
```

The above code made the whole app stop working!

I remembered that I used to do like that before but got no problem.

So, about `var x; ... x.trim();`, *Why sometimes it allows but sometimes it makes the rest of the code stop working?*

*And what is the best code practice for it?*

Comment: I think you mean "executed", not "implemented". And you probably get an exception in case `x` is not a string, which results in the following code not being executed.

Comment: Runtime error not coding error

Comment: Runtime errors are usually caused by coding errors.

Comment: The best practice is to see the exact error in the debug console, look at the stack trace and the error and diagnose what is causing the problem.  Nothing we can do here except make wild guesses.  You must learn how to properly debug a problem using the tools the browser makes available.

Comment: I mean: Coding err: If you program Java on eclipse if you miss declaring the code then there is red mark to ask you to fix your code.

Comment: Unlike in C++, Java, C#, etc. this kind of inspection is not always possible in dynamic languages such as JS or Python.

Comment: its exception you need to handle it

Comment: Javascript variable is not strictly typed and as such you need to make sure it is the right type before working with it.

Comment: why got voted down? if you can't answer it and vote it down? that's rude

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
if(typeof x === 'undefined'){
    // your get an error message
}
else
{
     var k=x.toString().trim();
}
```

Using strict equality operator `===` above is good idea there because in JS, you can name a variable as undefined too:

```
var undefined = "something";
```

So using === makes sure that you are really checking against undefined value for a variable.

Comment: What if `x` is a Number?

Comment: But in case of `x` being a number it will error any way ... and pass your undefined check

Comment: He told that in above comment "I not apply it to integer or anything. Just try "var x; x.trim();" "

Answer (score 0):

`trim` is a function of `String`. Refer [MDN - String.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

So when you apply it to an integer, it fails and throws error, causing you code to stop work

#### Example

```js
try{
  var a = 1;
  console.log(a.trim());
}
catch(ex){
  console.log(ex);
}
```

You can try to convert number to string using `.toString()` and then apply `.trim()`

```js
try{
  var a = 1;
  console.log(a.toString().trim());
}
catch(ex){
  console.log(ex);
}
```

Comment: I not apply it to  integer or anything. Just try "var x; x.trim();" cause error

Comment: Here x is `undefined` and undefined does not have any property called `.trim`

Answer (score 0):

I would expand Rajesh's answer. He's right, when you try to call a method that does not exist, a TypeError is thrown. The easiest and fool-proof approach would be to use try/catch to ensure that the rest of the code would be executed as it should. But it's likely that even if it does, you don't get the result you want.

I believe the best way to do would be to wrap the value you're having into String object. It's as easy as

```
var k = String(x).trim();
```

It does several important things:

1. Converts the value of `x`, whatever it be, into a string, i.e. when you check its type, it's always `'string'` and is always an instance of the String object.
2. Ensures that the resulting value has the method `trim` which does what it should.
3. Doesn't throw any error, so the rest of the code is executed.

There may be several pitfalls. If `x` is undefined, null, NaN or an object, the result of `String(x)` would be, correspondingly, `'undefined'`, `'null'`, `'NaN'`, or `'[object Object]'`. If `x` is an array, it's a specific case, and the value would be the same as if you call `x.join(',')`, for example

```
x = [1, 2, 3];
var k = String(x).trim; // k is now '1,2,3'
```

So always keep in mind what types you're dealing with.

Just as with String, you can cast variables to other types, but naïvely converting anything into a Number, a String or an Array is considered a very bad practice. You should always be somewhat sure what type you're working with.

Comment: What if I want to convert x to integer? var k= Integer(x);?

Comment: @Tom, in Javascript, there is no distinction between integer and double. There's just Number object for all of them. You can trim decimal part with `Math.ceil` or `Math.floor` static methods then. So, it's like `Math.floor(Number(x))`.